# Textfield text in InteractionDialog only shown when TextField has focus

Tags: codenameone

In an `InteractionDialog` of mine there is a `TextField`. I set the `TextField` style to a UIID defined in CSS. The `TextField` background is shown but not the text inside it

[image: no text appearing in the text field]

although

```
    System.err.println("The textfield contains " + nameTf.getText());
```

prints the expected text and the foreground color is 0 as expected. The text is only shown when I press inside the TextField but as soon as I press outside it disappears as shown below :

[image: text only appears when TextField has focus]

No EDT violation appears in the console.

The code used is the following :

```
   // Opens a dialog to input the name 
    nameButton.addActionListener((evt) -> {

        InteractionDialog nameDialog = new InteractionDialog();
        nameDialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER));

        // Hint for the user
        SpanLabel hintLabel = new SpanLabel("Indiquer un nom");
        hintLabel.setTextUIID(hintStyleName);

        TextField nameTf = new TextField(
                chosenAlarm.name.get() == null ? "Ma destination préférée" : chosenAlarm.name.get()
        );
        nameTf.setUIID(textFieldStyleName);
        System.err.println("The textfield colour is " + nameTf.getUnselectedStyle().getFgColor());

        // Validate text button
        Button validateNameButton = new Button("Valider >");
        validateNameButton.setUIID("ValidateButton");
        Container nameButtons = BoxLayout.encloseX(validateNameButton);

        validateNameButton.addActionListener((e) -> {
          // ...
        });

        nameDialog.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, nameTf);
        nameDialog.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH, hintLabel);
        // The buttons will be centered
        nameDialog.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, BorderLayout.centerCenter(nameButtons));

        // Shows the dialog in the center of the screen   
        nameDialog.showPopupDialog(nameButton);

    });
```

So it seems that whenever the `TextField` looses focus the text disappears. What should I do to show the text contained in the `TextField` even when the user does not press inside the `TextField` ?

Please note : the screen captures hide some elements since the app is Top Secret NSA Level ;-).

Any help appreciated,

Comment: Are there other text fields that work correctly in the app? Is it only the one within the interaction dialog? The one thing I see that's suspicious is placing the text field in the center of a border layout. Try placing it in a scrollable box Y container. Text fields behave badly when there is no room to scroll as the screen can't resize. Normally I would avoid text fields in dialogs (or interaction dialog) as it would make scrolling hard and that might have issues with the virtual keyboard on the device.

Comment: Thanks @ShaiAlmog. Actually this is the only one within the InteractionDialog so I don't think it might trigger scrolling issues. I tried with a Y-BoxLayout and it didn't change. What would you use instead of a TextField ?

Comment: We use text fields but try to put the UI in a location that works well with scrolling. This looks like a search field? In this case I would put it in the title and maybe even use the search feature builtin to Toolbar

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Indeed after some long trial and error I reached a very nice result : a placeholder has been added beneath the button and got animated after user's click. Then the placeholder will smoothly disappear thanks to unlayout.

Comment: Unfortunately the text still does not appear. It must have something to do with the styling then, doesn't it ? Yet the Component Inspector edit button does not work any longer on my Platform ("The EDIT action is not supported on the current platform!") so do you have hints on how to debug this ?

Comment: Removing the setUIID() solved the problem... sorry for the incovenience! Now I have to find what is wrong in my style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the issue was coming from the css style where I set the opacity to 255 (like in the theme designer with transparency). It had to be set to a value between 0 and 1.0 indeed.

```
MyTextFiledStyle {
color: #000000; 
background-color: #ffffff;
text-align: left;
opacity: 1.0; /*NOT 255 */
font-family: "native:MainLight";
```

}